# Bank ATM python assignment for school

Tags: python

Write a banking application called “Bank Of  ”.

Bank Of  prompts for a customer name and an associated user name. Bank Of  loops while prompting for:

1. Account creation (either chequing or savings)
2. Deposits
3. Withdrawals
4. Transfers from a chequing account to a savings account (or vice versa)
5. Display Transaction History.

Here is what i got so far.. i need help with the transfering from chequing to savings account..any help would be appreciated.

```
print("Hello, Welcome to Shawn's Bank ATM")
print("")
print("Please begin with creating an account")
name=input("Enter your name: ")
phone=input("Enter your phone number: ")
address=input("Enter your address: ")
code=input("Please enter a 4 digit pin to use as your passcode: ")

print()
print("Your account summary is:")
print("Name:" + name)
print("Phone Number:" + phone)     
print("Address:" + address)
print("Pin Code:" + code)    
print()
balance=float(input("Enter an amount to deposit into the account: "))
print()
print(name,", Thank you for creating an account.")
def printMenu():
    print()
    print("Please choose an option below:")
    print("""
    Enter b to Check your Balance
    Enter d to Deposit money into your Account
    Enter w to Withdraw money from your Account
    Enter q to Quit the Program """)
    print("")

def getTransaction():
    transaction=str(input("What would you like to do? "))
    return transaction

def withdraw(bal,amt):
    global balance
    balance=bal-amt
    if balance<0:
        balance=balance-10

def formatCurrency(amt):
    return "$%.2f" %amt

###MAIN PROGRAM###

printMenu()
command=str(getTransaction())

while command!="q":
    if (command=="b"):
        print(name,"Your current balance is",formatCurrency(balance))
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="d"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to deposit? "))
        balance=balance+amount
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    elif (command=="w"):
        amount=float(input("Amount to withdraw? "))
        withdraw(balance,amount)
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())
    else:
        print("Incorrect command. Please try again.")
        printMenu()
        command=str(getTransaction())

print(name,"Goodbye! See you again soon")
```

Comment: This all looks good, but if you want to transfer money from one account to another account, you'll need two accounts.  Right now, you only have one `balance`.  Also, I would make a `deposit()` function so that `transfer()` can simply call `withdraw()` on one account and `deposit()` on the other.  You will have to modify existing functions to take a balance as a parameter, so it is clear which balance to change.

Comment: thanks will, i was just wondering how exactly to prompt the user to make two accounts

Comment: Have you covered classes?

Comment: a little... but we havent gone in depth in it

Answer (score 0):

I would use an Account class in order to keep track of more than one account:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, accNum):
        self.balance = 0.0
        self.accNum = accNum

    def withdrawl(self, amount):
        self.balance -= amount

    # ETC
```

Then use your main loop to print options, take input and so on.  Note that since there are multiple accounts now, the user will have to specify which account to operate on, probably by account number.  Store your Account objects in a list so you can find them:

```
if UserRequestsNewAccount:
    new = Account(1234)
    ACCOUNTS.append(new)
```

Then to access them:

```
for acc in ACCOUNTS:
    if acc.accNum == RequestedAccountNumber:
        acc.withdraw(amount)
```

Otherwise, you could just have a list of doubles and refer to them by index.  Less fun, though. :)

EDIT:  The basic layout of your python file should be something like:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self):
        # fill in code here
    def deposit(self, amount):
        # fill in code here
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        # fill in code here
    def display_history(self):
        # fill in code here

ACCOUNTS = []
def main():
    while 1:
        print "choose an action: 1) new Account \n2) Withdraw .... etc"
        action = raw_input()
        if action == '1':
            print 'enter desired account number: '
            accNum = raw_input()
            new = Account(accNum)
            ACCOUNTS.append(new)
        elif action == '2':
            # fill in code here
        elif action == '3':
            # fill in code here
        elif action == '4':
            # fill in code here

main()
```

So the idea is to declare your class, then use another loop to control the handling of these objects.  Each choice will require some user input to specify what to do, then will call an `Account` method.  Account.history can just be a string which you append to after ever operation.

Comment: thank you so much will, but i was just wondering where exactly i would put these pieces of code into mine...(im really new to python :(

Comment: @Shawnayboy7 edited.  I think that if this seems way beyond what's covered in your class, you can just use two doubles named checking and savings, and operate on those.